# OS isnt detecting all of my RAM

Tags: ram, 21.04

Im kind of a newbie and sorry if this got answered alot already but i installed ubuntu first time on a new setup and it seems that it only uses 8,3 GB from my 16 GB.

using ubuntu 21.04

But Ubuntu seems to know it.
Here is a screenshot:
[image: 3 types of ram displayed]

this is the full memory check:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P4.80
       date: 03/10/2021
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
```

what did i do wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Bank 1 8G bank 3 8Gb how does that not add up to 16Gb? so this "OS isnt detecting all of my RAM" is NOT true. " it only uses 8,3 GB from my 16 GB." what do you have running that requires more then 8Gb? Mind that is says 8.3 so I would assume it is using more than 1 slot ...

Comment: Why is it shown so different everywhere? On system monitor it says X of 8.3 gb. So it sounds for me like it can only use 8.3 i also have problems when i use software which uses more than 7 gb

Comment: I don't see anything wrong?! the text you posted is about what is physical present and the other is about what is used. 2 different things to me

Comment: AMD or Intel processor. Desktop or laptop? If custom-build desktop, tell me the EXACT make/model # of your motherboard. Your RAM may be installed incorrectly. Show me the `top` and `free -h` commands.

Comment: @Rinzwind OP definitely has a problem. 16G RAM installed. OS (System Monitor) only sees 8G.